# Consulta Convertir dato SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Buenas soy novato en el tema y tengo una consulta que parece ser sencilla

actualmentemente tengo un store procedure en SQL server que al ingresar el parametro de la fecha devuelve el tipo de cambio en dolares de la fecha actual .

Pero este parametro es varchar(20) necesito convertirlo a datetime .

Adicional quiero guardar el resultado del store procedure en una variable,he asignarlo pero me marca error de sintaxis .

Por favor su ayuda .

```html
EXEC dbo.Usp_Sel_General_GetTipoCamMonRef_Filter '31/10/2018'
go
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con

Declare @fecha datetime = CONVERT(datetime, '31/12/2019 00:00:00', 103)

Comment: Lo intente y no retorno nada

Comment: En que idioma tienes la BD, el convert(date) varia de acuerdo al idioma y el fotmato de fecha que estas guardando, mira este link y ve en que formato te conviene hacer el convert https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: El numero que esta al final es el indicador del formato prueba con 120 tambien

Comment: Muchas gracias es con el formato 120

Answer (score 0):

Usa siempre formatos que no dependan de las configuraciones del lenguaje y fecha como son `YYYYMMDD` o `YYYYMMDD hh:mi:ss.mss` o `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi:ss.msss`.

En este caso, quedaría así:

```
EXEC dbo.Usp_Sel_General_GetTipoCamMonRef_Filter '20181031';
```